# NotificationListenerService not connecting to notification manager

Tags: android

I'm having trouble creating a service which extends `android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService`

As per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html I have added the following to the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
 android:label="@string/service_name"
 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I override `Service#onStartCommand`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got onStartCommand");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

and `NotificationListenerService#onListenerConnected`:

```
@Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got onListenerConnected");
}
```

When I run, though, starting the service with an explicit intent, I see that `onStartCommand` runs but not `onListenerConnected`. If I try and run `requestInterruptionFilter(NotificationListenerService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)`, from `onStartCommand` (which is what I want to do) I get `W/NotificationListenerService[NotificationListener]: Notification listener service not yet bound.`

Any idea why I'm not getting `onListenerConnected ()` (and thus can't send `requestInterruptionFilter`)?

This is on Lollipop 5.1.1 on Xperia Z1 compact.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Settings app
2. Sound & notification
3. Notification access
4. Your service name should be listed in this screen.
5. Check mark beside your service name

[image: Android 5.1 Notification access]

Android 5.1 Notification access screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Your app has to explicitly be allowef by the user to listen to notifications.  This will grant your service to run and recieve callbacks.  There is no way around it.

You need to find the option  somewhere in the Settings app.

Comment: I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>` in the manifest, is that not sufficient? Is there another permission to 'allow user to listen to notifications' ?

Comment: Just becasue you request the permission does not grant that you'll be able to listen to it. If you read the last sentence in my post, it'll point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically check if your application is given the permission with the following:

```
String notificationListenerString = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),"enabled_notification_listeners");
//Check notifications access permission
if (notificationListenerString == null || !notificationListenerString.contains(getPackageName())) {
    //The notification access has not acquired yet!
    Log.d(TAG, "no access");
    requestPermission();
}
else {
    //Your application has access to the notifications
    Log.d(TAG, "has access");
}
```

You can then setup a notification to point the user to enable the notification permission with requestPermission()

```
public void requestPermission() {
    Intent requestIntent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
    requestIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(requestIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To work correctly, you should grant notification access in the phone setting.

this setting is located in:

> Setting > Privacy > Special permissions > Notification access.

just search ***Notification access*** in the setting.

You can use this intent:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS))
else
    startActivity(Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"))
```

check your app name in the list.